# rfc 2694 DNS_ALG implementation on nAT(iptables) , anyone?

Tags: dns, packet, iptables

Can anybody tell me if theres any packet modification lib/utility that allows people to modify the packet at app level before sending them through NAT ?

eg. i want to change private ip returned in dns to its public equivalent.

Answers that dont work:
-I dont use static mapping from priv:public realms, so theres no question of setting up another dns server with public ips.
-Use cisco router.

So in short any lib/utility that goes along with iptables and allows user to modify payload of for eg. DNS packets.

I do not want to buy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QUEUE and NFQUEUE iptables targets pass the packet to a user-mode process, which is then free to drop the packet or modify it before sending on its way. The netfilter project provides a [C library](http://www.netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/index.html) to take care of getting packets in/out of the kernel for you; there are high-level bindings available too ([python-libnetfilter-queue](http://code.google.com/p/python-libnetfilter-queue/) and [nfqueue-bindings](http://software.inl.fr/trac/wiki/nfqueue-bindings) cater for Python and Perl respectively).

Alternatively, write a proxy to sit in front of your nameserver.

Comment: Isnt there a solution already existing for this, I was thinking there would ,because rfc 2694 is ancient> The DNS_ALG describes the behavior I want.

Comment: Your question sounded like you wanted to code this thing yourself. The age of the RFC is irrelevant; it was written by the implementors at Cisco and, since I'd imagine most networks use static mappings with split-horizon DNS, nobody else bothered to implement it (except in specialised cases like 'totd' for static IPv4-to-6 mappings). If there *is* an existing tool, you're more likely to find it by asking at Server Fault.

Comment: I dont want to code, but if theres nothing available I will have to :). I'll try asking this on server fault, but I didnt know that cisco guys wrote that stuff on twice natting and dns-alg.. Thnkx for the input though.